# How to use Google Places API with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-places-api

I have registration form in that i have address field , i want to add there google places.

```
 public mounted() {
    var input = document.getElementById("address");// what should be here in vue.js
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete();
  }
```

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I used above code for using my api key. but unable to write a function instead of `callback=initmap` as i have written in mounted function but it is giving me error while writing code `'google cannot find name 'google'' <= for this do i need to import or install anything?;

Comment: `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete()` your code doesn't know where to find this function, you maybe need to import a google library

Comment: @AppyGG how to import this? please let me know

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#loading_the_library Maybe there ?

Comment: @AppyGG I have gone through again but i am unable to add my project to console.google.developer.

Comment: @AppyGG Is there other way to add google libraries?

Comment: Have you tried `?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"` at the end instead of `?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"` ?

Comment: And have you tried to use third part component like one of these  https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-places or https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete ?

Comment: @AppyGG yes i tried but that was showing me problem in import statement . So i solved in this way...https://medium.com/dailyjs/google-places-autocomplete-in-vue-js-350aa934b18d it worked. thank you